# loader.js:800 throw err: node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a discord bot for my server and everytime I try to start the bot it gives me the same error every time.

I haven't tried anything else because a google search does not find the error.
I was following a YouTube video that was made in 2017.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
var prefix = config.prefix;

//Startup
client.login(config.token);

client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`Online ${new Date()}`);
client.user.setGame("Online");
});

client.on("message", async message => {
//Ingore bots
if(message.author.bot) return;

//Prefix in command
if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !==0) return;

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.legth).trim().split(/ 
+/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


if (command === "ping") {
    message.reply("Pong!");
}
});
```

I expected the bot to start fully but gave me the following error

```
"internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\adoss\Desktop\DiscordBot\config.json: Unexpected 
string in JSON at position 37
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.Module._extensions..json 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:27)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adoss\Desktop\DiscordBot\bot.js:3:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)"
```

Comment: Error message says it all: "SyntaxError: C:\Users\adoss\Desktop\DiscordBot\config.json: Unexpected 
string in JSON at position 37"

Comment: Ok I see now, Thanks!